# Is the CoHOG algorithm patented?

Tags: prior-art, data-processing-software, us20120057787

I would like to know if the *Co-occurrence Histograms of Oriented Gradients* (CoHOG) algorithm is patented. A [paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-92957-4_4) on it was published in 2009, and there seems to be a related patent application ([US 2012/0057787 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120057787)) with a later publication date.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes the patent application you cited has been granted as [US8428353](https://www.google.com/patents/US8428353) issued in 2013. Since the cited paper is behind a paywall, it is hard to assess whether it is sufficient prior art to invalidate the patent. Looking briefly at the claims, it seems to describe an algorithm without solving a specific problem. As such I'm wondering if it would hold up to more recent rulings on software patentability.

Answer (score 0):

The patent application you've linked to cannot claim the information disclosed in the paper.

It claims priority from a Japanese application that was filed on September 2, 2010. Japanese patent law allows only a 6 month grace period for filing after public disclosure of an invention. Because the paper you've linked to was published in 2009, based on a conference that was held on Jan 13–16, 2009, outside the grace period allowed for the Japenese application (and in fact, also outside the more liberal 1 year grace period allowed by the U.S.), that application (and the related US application) cannot claim the material that is disclosed in the paper. The paper counts as prior art.